# PostgreSQL | Busca com agregação

Tags: postgresql

Estou me batendo para trazer o número de vendas. Tentei fazer um join das tabelas, filtrei o que precisava e usei um count, mas não deu boa na parte de agregar.

[image: Saída Esperada]

[image: Saída Atual]

Código utilizado:

```
SELECT
    to_char(
        pay.created_at + 
            (SELECT utc_offset 
            FROM pg_timezone_names 
            WHERE name = 'America/Sao_Paulo'), 
        'YYYY/MM/DD'
            ) as "Data Pagamento",
            
    ord.status as "Status",
    
    count(*) as "Compras"

FROM
    orders as ord
    
INNER JOIN 
    payments as pay on ord.id = pay.order_id

WHERE
    ord.status = 'approved'
    and
    pay.status = 'approved'
    
GROUP BY
    pay.created_at, ord.status

ORDER BY
    pay.created_at asc
```

Comment: coloque na pergunta o resultado esperado

Comment: Você faz um `GROUP BY pay.created_at, ord.status` mas em sua saída esperada não consta o campo status. Não sei qual tipo de dado de seu campo `pay.created_at` mas você avaliou o uso de ` AT TIME ZONE`?

Comment: Obrigado pessoal! Funcionou com o at time zone. Abraços!